# Is there a simple way to add exFAT support?

Tags: filesystem, exfat

When I insert a USB stick or camera flash card I get the following error:

```
unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

Is there a simple way to add exFAT support to Ubuntu without kernel patching?

Comment: Three years later, the answers below do not work. The PPA 404'd so I'm assuming is no longer maintained. Solution: I used a different USB stick. Will reformat this one in Windows.

Comment: Worked for me on 2013-06-28 for Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google showed the answer... https://launchpad.net/~relan/+archive/exfat

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The better answer is http://askubuntu.com/a/85459/36661

Answer (score 31):

## Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 (13.10 and higher)

Adding additional ppas is no longer required. Also, it seems `fuse-exfat` is no longer installable. The package to install is now named `exfat-fuse` and is available by default (universe repository). The package `exfat-utils` will also add the usual filesystem management tools including this package. Also thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/364298/28323)

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

## Ubuntu 12.04 (13.04 and lower)

A more detailed, step-to-step description on how to use the PPA pointed to by StalkerNOVA can be found [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6769597/923794), copied here for the sake of completeness:

Do only once:

1. Add the repository: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:relan/exfat`
2. Update the package list: `sudo apt-get update`
3. Install the exfat package: `sudo apt-get install fuse-exfat`
4. Create the mount folder: `sudo mkdir /media/exfat`

Everytime you want to access sdxc the card/exfat filesystem:

5. Mount the filesystem (replace sdc1 with your exfat partition): `sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdc1 /media/exfat`
   On some devices, cameras, for locked sdxc cards etc you might want to mount the filesystem read only, just add `-o ro` to the mount command line: `sudo mount -t exfat -o ro /dev/sdc1 /media/exfat`
6. Read and write to /media/exfat to your heart's desire.
7. When you are done, unmount the filesystem: `sudo umount /media/exfat`

The `sdc1` in the step-by-step above refers to the linux device where your card/exfat filesystem resides on. If this changes (usb card readers, cameras) or you simply don't know which one it could be either use the menu system `System` -> `Administration` -> `Disk Util` and usually you will find your camera or card reader in the list on the left hand side. Or - as a quick shortcut - use `cat /proc/partitions` on a terminal command line. The latter is only useful if you know all the other unchanging device names on your system and thus can quickly identify the one added one.

Comment: With Ubuntu 12.04, you only need points 1 to 3 (add ppa, update, install). Automount will work as usual.

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 14.04 there is a package called exfat-fuse. The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse
```