# How do I open a memory stick formatted with exfat?

Tags: mount

I receive the following error message when I try to access my san disk 64 GB memory from my android phone.

```
Error mounting: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

Comment: Android is not supported here, only Ubuntu and derivatives.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a simple way to add exFAT support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14838/is-there-a-simple-way-to-add-exfat-support)

Comment: This is ontopic, he's talking about mounting the memory stick in ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable exFat support in Ubuntu.

See here how : [Is there a simple way to add exFAT support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14838/is-there-a-simple-way-to-add-exfat-support)