# Mounting partion (FAT) fails

Tags: mount, disk

I have several windows drives, allthough I'ḿ not using Windows anymore but too many data on it. Is there a way to convert the filesystems without losing the data or how to fix this issue?

I have 4 drives, 3 of them are mounted, one isn't and gives me following error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdh2 at /media/andreas/photo's: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdh2" "/media/andreas/photo's"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat' (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Comment: Is it FAT32, or exFAT? Are **you** typing this command, or is this being automatically mounted by Ubuntu? Or do you have an entry in `/etc/fstab`? If you know it's exFAT, or it's being automatically mounted, then you need to add exFAT support. Just follow the first 3 steps in the answer here: [Is there a simple way to add exFAT support?](http://askubuntu.com/q/14838/52726)

Comment: you solution worked perfect ly till step 3 on it run like acharm :)

Comment: ow btw it tried to mount automaticly but i was 100% it was fat32 but it seems to be exFAT