# Mount error: "unknown filesystem type 'exfat'"

Tags: mount, filesystem, exfat

When trying to mount an exfat filesystem, I get the following error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda6 at /media/gkp/Backup: Command-line 
`mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sda6" "/media/gkp/Backup"' 
exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

Exfat is used on some USB sticks and camera sd cards. What can I do to mount this type of filesystem?

Comment: Please provide the version of Ubuntu you are using. As you can see there is more than 1 answer for Ubuntu.

Comment: see also http://askubuntu.com/a/85459/20972 (esp. for 13.10)

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 is doing this.

Comment: In my case, I had to also add the universe repository:
`sudo add-apt-repository universe`
`sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a drive formatted with exfat working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370398/how-to-get-a-drive-formatted-with-exfat-working)

Comment: Ran into this today on Debian (bookworm/sid, 5.15.5-1) and noted suspicious error in /var/log/mesages: `Jan  4 15:36:57 fractal kernel: [18438.261624] failed to validate module [exfat] BTF: -22`

Answer (score 664):

You get this error because the exfat filesystem is not installed in Ubuntu by default. [exFAT is proprietary and patented by Microsoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT#Restrictive_licensing_and_software_patents).

## Ubuntu 13.10 or higher

Since Ubuntu 13.10, this package is in the main repository. Just install `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils`:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

## Ubuntu 12.04

For ubuntu 13.04 and lower, you'll need a ppa to install the `exfat` support. Installation procedure:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:relan/exfat
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fuse-exfat
```

If you see the error `gpg: "tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted" not a key ID: skipping` during the `apt-add-repository` step, then you'll need to manually install the signing key and run the `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` steps after that:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4DF9B28CA252A784
```

​​​​​​

Comment: looks like for 13.10 you don't even need the ppa it's just `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse` ref: http://askubuntu.com/a/85459/20972

Comment: I followed same, after doing all steps at last it saying 
"FUSE exfat 1.0.1
ERROR: failed to open `/dev/sdd1'." any suggestion?

Comment: :) and after then sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1 help me to get mount. wait for few second it could time to mount.

Comment: +1. On Ubuntu 14.04, no PPA is needed. I was able to `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse` and, after installation, my 64GB SD CARD mounted as soon as I plugged it in.

Comment: @DrewNoakes - Yeah this command also works with 15.10 thankx.

Comment: This worked in linux mint. thanls!

Comment: It works in Ubuntu 15.10 too!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils` Works on 16.04!

Comment: And just like this it works on ubuntu 14.04 - Thank you!  Love this database.  You posted this message more than 3 years ago.  TNX

Comment: is there a solution in case the system is not connected to the internet

Comment: Worked for me. Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: And now 18.04, still good. Yay! = `sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`

Comment: And since we're playing this game, 19.04 also!

Comment: FWIW my camera SD card reader in 18.04 only required `exfat-fuse` and not `exfat-utils`

Comment: DO NOT advise people to update their operating system to install some tools. Only if the tools fail to install should they do an update. This can break so much stuff...

Answer (score 4):

As of November 25, 2019, this does not work yet in Ubuntu 19.10 Eoan, probably because apt just cannot grab exfat-fuse. I fixed this problem by [downloading exfat-fuse deb directly](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/19.10/ubuntu-universe-amd64/exfat-fuse_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb.html).
This is after installing a [dependency](https://debian.pkgs.org/10/multimedia-main-amd64/libtxc-dxtn0_1.0.1-dmo3_amd64.deb.html).

Comment: This worked, thankyou!

Comment: As of Dec 11, it does seem to fetch `exfat-fuse` properly.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 installing `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` works.  Yet I have this error `FUSE exfat 1.3.0
ERROR: failed to read boot sector.`

Comment: This is either because your device wasn't set up correctly, or could also be because your exfat device is somehow 'not good' e.g. corrupt, full, or physically malfunctioning. Try with another device you've worked with before and if that works then try remake the failed device

Comment: Upgraded to 20.10, installed `exfatprogs`.  Mounting works randomly.  Moreover, if the card is inserted directly (is SD slot of Macbookpro), it is always read-only.  If it is connected through a card reader, write is possible.

Comment: I would bet on this being a firmware related issue unrelated to the question, it sounds like  your device is supported partially on different platforms

Comment: I'm seeing something like it in Debian Bullseye although it worked in Buster.  Somebody's screwing around with something again and breaking things.  I have exfat-fuse and exfatprogs.  Taking my card to a different box to read it.

Comment: On a Raspberry Pi with Buster the same card and reader worked fine.  It's the card from my better Nikon, I use it fairly often.

Answer (score 0):

After installing exfat-fuse and exfat-utils, don't just wait, like silly me, unplug and replug the USB device.