# How to get a drive formatted with exfat working?

Tags: filesystem, exfat

In Ubuntu 13.04 there was an option to use the `PPA by Relan` in order to get ExFat functionality. Seeing that in Ubuntu this functionality is now available from the repositories without the PPA I tried this but failed to make it work.

So my question is how do I enable exfat support?

Comment: Odly enough, when searching the term exfat in the software center I can still find the fuse-utils (after showing technical items) but after clicking on it, it says "Not found - There isn’t a software package called “fuse-exfat” in your current software sources."

Answer (score 295, accepted):

Turns out the packages from the official repositories do the trick. Just install `exfat-utils` and `exfat-fuse` packages using the package manager of your choice, or just using `apt-get` from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse
```

This should delivery a working exfat file system (read and write support, but not formatting the drives with exfat via Gnome Disks and GParted).

<sub>From 13.04+ it hasn't been necessary but if you're using 12.04 you *might* need to reboot your computer before you can mount your exfat partition. If it isn't working for you after installing the packages, try rebooting.</sub>

Comment: For me, this now works even without a reboot. Using Ubuntu 13.10 x64.

Comment: Worked perfectly without reboot to get Ubuntu to recognize a Samsung T1 external SSD. Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly! No reboot required! If it doesn't want to work directly after the installation, then just unplug the drive and plug it back in...

Comment: I had to reboot, for 15.04. but It works great.

Comment: Didn't have to reboot with Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: exfat-fuse alone was enough on my Ubuntu 15. No reboot required,

Comment: Worked perfectly in Ubuntu 16.04 with a WD drive formatted with exfat. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to access a microSD card. After installing exfat-utils and exfat-fuse on 16.04 and plugging the card reader I get the error message : "Can't open a folder for <card name>" and "No application is registered to manage this file". I have no idea how to solve this one.

Comment: I found out that in my case /media/<user> was created with ownership set to root:root. Once I changed it to <user>:<user> I could access the data and navigate in it using the file navigator.

Comment: I know, this is very late, but... OMG! Thank you! You're a life saver :D

Comment: Works perfect for 16.04 - no reboot needed just unplugged the thumbdrive and plugged it back in

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS only requires `sudo apt install exfat-utils exfat-fuse`

Comment: What to do on 14.04?

Comment: UbuntuStudio 19.04 only needs `exfat-utils` explicitly.  That also grabs `exfat-fuse` automatically as a dependency.  I can read my camera now.

Comment: In Ubuntu 23.04, I get this error: "E: Package 'exfat-utils' has no installation candidate"

Answer (score 21):

Finally get it to work on my 13.10.

I did:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:relan/exfat
sudo apt-get install fuse  # (only fuse)
```

and lastly

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse   # (instead of fuse-exfat)
```

Plugged my External HD and it's working read/write.

Comment: I'm not sure what's changed, but this seems to be no longer necessary as the official packages, `exfat-utils` and `exfat-fuse` work just fine for me.

Comment: if you are formatting your own exfat volume, make sure to set the partition id to ntfs, not fat---otherwise, OSX will not recognize it.  at least, this is what it took on my system.

Answer (score 6):

I just did a successful install on 4/3/2014 with Ubuntu 13.10, fully updated, using only this command:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install exfat-utils`

No restart required, and the drive auto-mounted with full read/write support.

Answer (score 5):

`fuse-utils` moved to `fuse`. `fuse-utils` has been a trasitionary metapackage (something that just depends on the new package name) since 12.04.

That doesn't help you much if you have something that has a package dependency on `fuse-utils` because you're right, the metapackage has been removed now. The simplest thing to do might be to just download [the Raring version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/fuse-utils) and install that. It shouldn't hurt anything as it makes no demands on which version of `fuse` to install, just that there's one installed.

Comment: Hi @Oli I will try that. Thanks for the tip. Will write how it worked.

Comment: @davorao If it's any consolation, it *might* be mainline (and not need fuse) by the next Ubuntu release. There already is a kernel driver but it's not quite ready yet, from what I can see.

Comment: It is actually. The Raring version wouldn't quite want to work, so I will wait and see how it evolves over time. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 23.04, here's how to install support for the exFAT filesystem:

```
sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfatprogs
```