# Broken Windows flashdrive after sudo cp

Tags: usb, windows, files

I copied a PDF file on Ubuntu to my Windows-formatted flashdrive with

```
sudo cp file.pdf /mnt/sdb4/
```

(I am not sure if /mnt/sdb4/ was the path though).

Now I can't access the drive neither from Windows nor from Linux(it doesn't appear in My Computer).
I don't want to format it as there were some important files on it. How can I fix it?

Comment: Insert your USB to the system and then run `lsblk` command. Finally post it's output on your question.

Comment: Hi Avinash. I've updated the question.

Comment: @enedil Why you remove the output of `lsblk` command from the OP's question?

Comment: What's the file system of your usb drive?

Comment: It was Windows-formatted FAT(probably 32). I think that copying this file broken the filesystem in some way.

Comment: post the output of `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb` command in your question along with the input.

Comment: command: `sudo mount/dev/sdb1 /media/usb`, output: `mount: you must specify the filesystem type`

Comment: it's not `sudo mount/dev/sdb1 /media/usb`, it's `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb`

Comment: spaces are very important.

Comment: @Avinash Raj when I started editing, the output wasn't present.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below commands on terminal(ctrl+Alt+T) to mount your USB drive manually,

```
sudo mkdir /media/usb
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
```

Now the files in your USB  would be found on `/media/usb` directory.

Comment: When I do `sudo mount/dev/sdb1 /media/usb` I get `mount: you must specify the filesystem type`. After adding `-t vfat` I get `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error`

Comment: post the output of `sudo blkid` command in your question.

Comment: if you want to mount an exfat partition then follow this http://askubuntu.com/a/451376/202806