# unable to mount external exfat hdd on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mount, hard-drive, macbook, exfat

Following error is being popped when I connect my harddrive and try to open it:

**Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/anvesha/EXTERNAL: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/anvesha/EXTERNAL"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: stdout:`FUSE exfat 1.2.3 ' stderr: `ERROR: '._.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent' has invalid checksum (0xd73 != 0xa97). '**

I copied some files from Macbook before. Then I used it on my linux laptop, it worked fine. But after few days, when I plugged it in back, this error showed up. Help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable exFAT in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451364/how-to-enable-exfat-in-ubuntu-14-04)