# cannot mount mount 64 GB Volume

Tags: media, exfat

Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/sda/6332-3433: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/sda/6332-3433"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'

Comment: Care to share a bit more info on your setup? Can you paste your `/etc/fstab`, the output of `mount`  and possibly `lsblk`?

Comment: This should help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/451364/how-to-enable-exfat-in-ubuntu-14-04#451376

Answer (score 1):

You need to install exfat utilities to mount a exfat formatted Filesystem.

```
sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

should do the trick, and enable you to mount the drive.