# Mount Sandisk Cruzer 2.0

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I recently bought a Sandisk Cruzer Force USB flash drive, and my problem is that I am unable to mount it. In fact am new to Ubuntu and I really don't know how to mount a USB drive on Linux. At present I use Ubuntu 13.10 as my OS. I don't have any Windows sharing with this. I don't have partitions on my system. I tried `sudo fdisk -l` and got these results:

```
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 4152 MB, 4152360960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 504 cylinders, total 8110080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 4152 MB, 4152360960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 504 cylinders, total 8110080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x15b11843

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition table.
```

I want this USB drive to get mounted. Please help.

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive

Comment: That link has instructions that is even easier than formatting the USB with GParted.

Comment: The flash drive is likely already formatted. You may find this is unnecessary.

Comment: Please indicate the size of the USB drive. Larger drives may be in ExFAT format. I am not sure Ubuntu 13.10 has support for this format installed by default. In that case, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/370398/how-to-get-a-drive-formatted-with-exfat-working

Comment: This saved me a whole lot of trouble with a corrupted usb stick https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive

Answer (score 3):

1) plug in your flash drive

2) Open a terminal and issue the command `dmesg`

you should see your device name listed at the bottom like this: mine is /dev/sdc. yours may be different. Use the /dev/sd? entry that you see. I will use /dev/sdc.

[image: ff1]

3) **If your device is preformatted** like mine the system will automatically mount it and you will have to unmount it with the command `sudo umount /dev/sdc1`

4)To format to the FAT filesystem for maximum compatibility with other operating systems issue the following command in the terminal:

`sudo mkdosfs -n 'Label' -I /dev/sdc` replacing Label with the label you would like your drive to have.

5) When the command has finished, you can simply unplug the drive and plug it back in. The system will recognize it and it will show in your file manager like this:

[image: ff3]