# Error mounting microSD card on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount, micro-sd

I recently got a microSD card for a music player, I've tried to mount this on my computer to transfer music but have got the following error:

Unable to mount 127 GB Volume

> Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/blank/9C33-6BBD: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/blank/9C33-6BBD"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'

I'm trying to mount the microSD via a usb adapter - I've tried 2 different adapters with no difference.
My system is Ubuntu 14.04.

I've run

```
lsusb
sudo fdisk -l
```

and the results are:

> ```
>    blank@blank:~$ lsusb
> Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
> Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0420:1307 Chips and Technologies Celly SIM Card Reader
> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
> Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
> Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
> Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
> Bus 010 Device 002: ID 04d9:0499 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Optical Mouse
> Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
> Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> blank@blank:~$ sudo fdisk -l
> [sudo] password for blank:
> ```

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4eb6e04c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   212700599   106350268+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       212701184   391024639    89161728   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       391026686  1953523711   781248513    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      1919977472  1953523711    16773120   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       391026688  1919977471   764475392   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 127.0 GB, 126968922112 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15436 cylinders, total 247986176 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1           32768   247986175   123976704    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Any pointers as to what the issue is and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your SD is formatted with exFAT, which Ubuntu does not support natively. You have to install some extra packages to gain access to exFAT volumes. Please follow this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/374627/367990).