# Error when attempting to access external hard drive Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount, hard-drive

When I try to click on my external hard drive I get a pop-up error that reads

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/andrew/Untitled: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/andrew/Untitled"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

What is the issue here, and how can I go about fixing it?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You might find your answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/370398/how-to-get-a-drive-formatted-with-exfat-working).

Comment: Terrance is right. You'll find the answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to enable the universe repository. If you have not done it already, run:

> `sudo add-apt-repository universe`, then update the system with:
>
> `sudo apt-get update`

Install the below packages to auto mount your exFAT formatted device:

> `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`

or continue with the manual mount as you were trying.