# Read a windows Hard Disk

Tags: mount, hard-drive

My PC was configured to dual boot windows and ubuntu, until... the SSD died.

I have a 3TB hard disk with almost all my data which I had been using when booting through windows.  I only used the 3TB disk in the windows environment, (all my Ubuntu data is gone, ouch!)

I am getting another SSD drive today and am wondering if it will be possible to mount the 3TB drive via the Ubuntu OS and thereby skip buying another copy of Windows, (I can't find the original windows CD)?

Comment: What format is the 3tb disk ? If NTFS then `yes`, if exfat then http://askubuntu.com/questions/370398/how-to-get-a-drive-formatted-with-exfat-working

Comment: Yes , ubuntu will read (mount) the hard drive. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if **ntfs-3g** is installed.

> ntfs-3g --version

If not, install it

> sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g

With this utility you can mount and read/write NTFS files.

Comment: You don't need to do this, I have two NTFS drives and they mount just fine, NTFS-3g is pre installed in Ubuntu, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions