# Problem with opening USB flash drive stick

Tags: usb

help. I’m new to Ubuntu and the usb ports seem to work (mouse...) but when i try to insert a memory stick appears:

Device `/dev/sdb1` is already mounted at `/media/usb0`

and the I can't read or write or even change permissions...

thanks

```
file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass> proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0 # / was on /dev/sda1 during installation UUID=eb6986f2-f3cc-47bb-b869-946a2363162e / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1 # swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation UUID=7c36b676-63f1-4856-bacc-dc0748a0916e none swap sw 0 0

/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro) proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) 
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) 
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw) none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw) none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw) 
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw) udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755) devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620) tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)

none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880) 
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev) 
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755) 
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw) binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,
none,name=systemd) gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=hugo)
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of: cat /etc/fstab and mount PS: I would have used a comment for this, but i need 50 rep, so i will update this answer (hopefully with a solution)

Comment: Is your flash drive ntfs formatted? If so you may need to install ntfs-3g package to modify contents of it.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try.

1) I have had problems with read exFat 
If it is exFat try this [ask ubuntu exFat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370398/how-to-get-a-drive-formatted-with-exfat-working)

2)  if not exFat, hahah..not joking, Stick you usb in a windows machine.  See if it automatically fixes it, then stick it back in your linux box.   (The linux kernel actually gives a message sometimes to do this!)