# Unable to access on SD Card

Tags: mount, sd-card, remote-access, storage, fat32

suddenly I get an error on my SD Card (look at the image) and now I can't see what it is inside it or use it. I never done any works or something strange since I've bought it months ago. I think it's like a problem with some partition. Can anyone help me? I don't want to lose all of mine pics :( Thanks in advice for ur attetion[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaQWi.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my read of the image that you posted, the issue appears to be `unknown filesystem type 'exfat'`.

A bit of searching turned up [this related exfat discussion](https://askubuntu.com/q/370398/32664), with a potential solution (you don't mention the version of Ubuntu that you're running). In short, your install of Ubuntu may be missing the exfat packages that should allow you to correctly read the SD card. Those packages can be installed with:

`sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse`