# Unable to format SD Card (Unable to Format it and locked in read only mode)

Tags: partitioning, mount, sd-card

I had a problem on my SD Card. When I try to format it both from system and from Gparted Partition Editor I can't finish the operation for some errors. I also tryed on windows but he says to me that the card it's in only read mode, but I'm sure that it was not only in read mode.

I'm impossibilitate to use my SD into my smartphone cause for this problem the phone can't read it..same on PC, I can read the data on it but I'm impossilitate to write or erase on it.

Some days ago I had problems on the SD..treated on this question [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987570/unable-to-access-on-sd-card?noredirect=1#comment1590939_987570)

This is the message from Gparted (When I try do do any format operation) 
[image]

And this is the message alert, still form Gparted

```
Unable to read the contents of this file system! Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
```

Thank in advice!!

Comment: The SD card might be damaged, 'gridlocked', but there might be other things, that prevent you from writing to it. Please try according to the list in the following link. You might be able to make it work, https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035

Comment: Yep I readed It but It gives me no help 

Comment: Do you mean that the SD card is still read-only after testing those alternatives? In that case I am sorry, but it is probably gridlocked, in other words damaged beyond what a regular user (like you and me) can do.

Comment: *If you can still read the flles, please copy them now* (as soon as possible) to another drive, because if the card is gridlocked, it is the first step of a failing process, and the next step might come soon; that it will be completely dead.

Comment: Just done a Big Backup..The problem is that I can't do any sort of formatting on it... I think that the problem is from the file system. " I think the problem is that the file system is in exFAT and this FileSystem works properly only on windows.. is possible to format with this FS on ubuntu or I need any windows machine?" (From the commet below)

Answer (score 0):

If you look on the SD card reader, you will see a switch, and flip the switch to format it.
[Switch on the sd card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRw2y.png)

Comment: Yep, the swith is on the right position, however thanks. I think the problem is that the file system is in exFAT and this FileSystem works properly only on windows.. is possible to format with this FS on ubuntu or I need any windows machine?

Comment: Happened to me and I could never use it again. I had a 2 gb drone sd card and it never had write access and damaged my drone camera too. It used to though.

Comment: @GiovanniGiampaolo, I don't think the file system makes the problem, when you want to format the drive. But if you think so, you can try according to this link (to make Ubuntu work with exFAT), https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706 ; By the way, in the original question you wrote that Windows failed too (and it has built-in support for exFAT).

Comment: Yep, Windows says that cannot format the SD cause it's in only read mode. But I'm sure that was not! So if it's not the file system..what can be the problem? I already saved all the files and now I need a way to use the SD Normally again.

Comment: @GiovanniGiampaolo, You could try in another computer, with another card reader etc, but at some point you must give up. -- I read from your description, that the problem is that the SD card is 'gridlocked'. It means that it is damaged beyond repair. I am glad that you have saved all the files from it, but I an sorry, I do not think that you can write to it again.

Comment: I try as you say and I hope that I will restore this SD bought only 6 Months ago! =(