# Ubuntu can not open my SD card

Tags: mount

Ubuntu will not open my SD card from the built in reader. It was working in Windows.
[image: error displayed]

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of installing the ExFat utility packages.

`sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse`

Based on experiences in the comments it looks like it is recommended to reboot the machine before trying to mount the ExFat drive.

See the below question.

[How to get a drive formatted with exfat working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370398/how-to-get-a-drive-formatted-with-exfat-working)

Comment: @Mods Not sure if question is a Dupe but answering for the sake of assisting Rapidrob

Comment: Data downloaded from the above link. I insert the SD card and I have to go to "computer" to see the card. It had been listed as it's own "place " before.

Comment: I used the above link and it loaded data. The CD card is no longer under "places" as it was before. It is hidden under "computer" If I try to open the SD card,nothing happens.It is just highlighted and nothing happens even if I say "open"

Comment: I rebooted the laptop the second time and it opened the CD card.Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! If the answer worked for you you can click the checkmark under my answer to accept it as the answer, this helps everyone including the community out.

Comment: I would if I could see a check mark.