# unable to mount external hard disk error coming

Tags: mount

when inserting the hard disk, following error is coming
Error mounting: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a drive formatted with exfat working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/370398/how-to-get-a-drive-formatted-with-exfat-working)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/364270/mount-error-unknown-filesystem-type-exfat

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the exfat utilites first. Follow the directions in this previously answered question:
[How to get a drive formatted with exfat working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370398/how-to-get-a-drive-formatted-with-exfat-working)