# Unable to mount my external exfat disk

Tags: 16.04, mount, exfat

It is saying this:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc2 at /media/sudheer/Untitled:
  Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,
  iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdc2" 
  "/media/sudheer/Untitled"' 
exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

Comment: On 16.04.4 one can drop the `-get` suffix, i.e. `sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils` is all that is needed.

Answer (score 71):

You get this error because the exfat filesystem is not installed in Ubuntu by default. [exFAT is a proprietary and patented by Microsoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT#Restrictive_licensing_and_software_patents).

Since Ubuntu 13.10, this package is in the main repository. Just install `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils`:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Source: Pablo Bianchi - [Mount unknown filesystem exfat](https://askubuntu.com/a/364298/723536)

Comment: no need to disconnect the drive after installation, just click it again in nautilus

Comment: I am getting these errors even after installation ...