# Unable to Mount flash or hard drive on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mount, hard-drive, exfat

Whenever I try to mount flash drives or hardrives I get the following message:

> Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/tony/0457-C92C: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/tony/0457-C92C"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'

Screenshot:
[image: SCreenshot with the message]

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: It seems this question is already answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/364270/mount-unknown-filesystem-exfat

Answer (score 8):

You need to install the support for the Exfat filesystem; it's not installed by default.

`sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`

See also "http://unixnme.blogspot.ro/2016/04/how-to-mount-exfat-partition-in-ubuntu.html" on the [Unix and Me](http://unixnme.blogspot.ro/2016/04/how-to-mount-exfat-partition-in-ubuntu.html) blog.

Comment: You were 2 secs faster :-/

Comment: @RoVo: Nevermind two seconds, have a +1 for the confirmation.

Comment: `exfat-utils` is not necessary to mount ExFAT.

Answer (score 7):

> unknown filesystem type 'exfat'

You need to [install exfat](https://www.howtogeek.com/235655/how-to-mount-and-use-an-exfat-drive-on-linux/). Unfortunately it does not come preinstalled in Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Comment: Ok but now it doesn't read the flash drive. The error doesn't occur but it doesn't automatically mount.

Comment: did you restart, maybe that can help.

Comment: `exfat-utils` is not necessary to mount ExFAT.